# Where is the sun visor?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I'm playing Euro Truck Sim 2 and run into a small snag that I never thought would affect me in a game.

I'm driving east towards Hungary and the rising sun is shining directly in my eyes preventing me from seeing upcoming hazards and traffic.

Is there a sun visor I can enable?

Comment: Are you using a specific truck or just in general

Comment: @Kunal Just in general

Answer (score 3):

In the customisation options for most trucks, above the windshield on external accessories, there should be a slot for a sun visor.

Comment: If not just search for a sunvisor mod for thw model of truck you are using